# Tkinter .geometry() isn't resizing the window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tkinter .geometry() function is not channging the size of the window even though it should when i press  and I know the function is running cause i asked it to print that it's running to the console. Here is the code.

```
import tkinter

class FullScreenWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.window.attributes('-zoomed', True)
        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.state = False
        self.window.bind("<F11>", self.toggleFullscreen)
        self.window.bind("<Escape>", self.smallScreen)

    def toggleFullscreen(self, event=None):
        self.state = not self.state
        self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", self.state)

    def smallScreen(self, event=None):
        self.state = False
        self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", self.state)
        print("I am running")
        self.window.geometry("600x525")

fsw = FullScreenWindow()

fsw.window.mainloop()
```

Comment: We don't want or need to see your complete code in this case. Please create a **minimal** example the reproduces your problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Define "does nothing". The only time for me is, when this happens, when full-screen mode is set. Therefore, the minimal addition to your code is to disable full-screen mode in `smallScreen` just before `.geometry`. Same goes for the `zoomed` state, so you should revert this state to `normal` on `smallScreen`.

Comment: @martineau I will simplify the code now that I know what the problem and solution is and will look into that and try to postsimpler code in the future.

Comment: @acw1668: no, that's not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CommonSense got it right. The '-zoomed' was overriding the changes that i wanted to make with .geometry. By adding

```
self.window.atrributes('-zoomed', False)
```

into the smallScreen function.

Here is the fixed code

```
import tkinter

class FullScreenWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.window.attributes('-zoomed', True)
        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.state = False
        self.window.bind("<F11>", self.toggleFullscreen)
        self.window.bind("<Escape>", self.smallScreen)

    def toggleFullscreen(self, event=None):
        self.state = not self.state
        self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", self.state)

    def smallScreen(self, event=None):
        self.state = False
        self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", self.state)
        self.window.attrebutes("-zoomed", self.state)
        self.window.geometry("600x525")

fsw = FullScreenWindow()

fsw.window.mainloop()
```